# Перенос строки после обработки real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysqli

При добавлении текста в базу вместо переноса строки добавляются обратные слеши \r\n

```
<?php
#public function escape($str)
#{
#    return $this->mysqli()->real_escape_string($str);
#}

header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
require_once 'inc.php';
$lolo = 'dfdfs
dsfsd
dsfsd';
$data = array(
    "im" => 'G17',
    "info" => $db->escape($lolo));

$db->insert('dog', $data);
?>
```

на выходе получаю:

> dfdfs\r\ndsfsd\r\ndsfsd

Если не обрабатывать текст функцией `real_escape_string` то все нормально, а обработка мне нужна.

Comment: А "на выходе" это где ? операция insert в mysql развернет ваши \r\n в нормальные переводы кареток. Но вы тут пользуетесь неким классом, который делает insert. Посмотрите текст этого класса, может он так же что то делает со строкой и превращает при записи в базу ваши переводы кареток например в \\r\\n ...

Comment: В таблице. Эти символы появляются после обработки функцией real_escape_string , если не обрабатывать то все нормально пишется в базу.

Comment: покажите что делает ваш класс на операции insert. надо увидеть сам SQL запрос `insert into ... ` что бы хоть что то понять. В идеале распечатайте саму сформированноую команду insert перед отправкой в базу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> а обработка мне нужна.

Не нужна.

Функция insert должна обрабатывать данные самостоятельно.
И, судя по результатам, она это и делает.

Так что надо просто убрать этот кустарный код с $db->escape и все заработает нормально.